# If I own a vtxo of 10000 sats, can I leave the ark only for 5000 sats?

Tags: ark

Let's say somebody sent me 10000 sats offchain to get me on board and I want to take back onchain (unilateral exit) only part of them, like for example 5000 sats.

I could send 5000 sats to another address of mine offchain and then leave the Ark, but can  I do the same without making another offchain transaction?

Answer (score 3):

There are two answers here.

First of all, **you cannot unilaterally exit with partial vtxos**. For a unilateral exit, you always have to exit entire vtxos.

For **collaborative exits, or "lift outs", it is possible**. What would happen is exactly the same as if you wanted to lift out the entire value, but you would also get an additional "change" vtxo. So in return for a 10 000 sats vtxo, you could f.e. get a 5 000 sats utxo and then a 5 000 sat vtxo (ignoring fees here of course).

See [this answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/120031/1307) for how the collaborative exit works. Now imagine in that diagram that you also get an `A'*` vtxo in the vtxo tree on the right hand side.